# How to map indexed JSON with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to map a JSON like this into a list of Objects:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Peter Parker",
    "alias": "peter"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Berry Allen",
    "alias": "berry"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tony Stark",
    "alias": "tony"
  }
}
```

I'm struggling especially with the index number. Without these consecutive numbers I would do something like the following, which is working with 'normal' object arrays very well.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<People> people = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<People>>(){});
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON structure represents a map, not a list:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, People> peopleMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, People>>(){});
Collection<People> allPeople = peopleMap.values();
```